# How to resolve "JDBC-5072:Failure converting NUMBER to or from a native type" error in tibero?

Tags: tibero

We are getting two different execution response for the same kind of scripts in Tibero.

It Accepts the below script without any error:

```
 Insert into ABCD(LINKNAME,NAME,VALUE) values ('KH_CIF_ACC_LIST_INQ_LINK_ID','AddressLocation','http://170.12.3.185:2044/axis2/services/WS_Engine_stub?wsdl');
```

Not Accepting the below script:

```
 Insert into ABCD(LINKNAME,NAME,VALUE) values ('KH_CUSTOMER_ONBOARDING_LINK_ID','AddressLocation','http://170.12.3.185:2044/axis2/services/WS_Engine_stub?wsdl');
```

Getting the below Error:

```
 JDBC-5072:Failure converting NUMBER to or from a native type.
```